# How to translate 周同比 into English?

Tags: translation

In the context of statistical trends, what is the English translation of `周同比`? This phrase appears as an annotation on a chart, which shows upward and downward trends.

**Google Translate** translates it as `Week of the same week`, which does not make any sense to me. Breaking it down:

**周**

```
noun
week, periphery, circumference, cycle, Zhou Dynasty, circuit

adjective
all, attentive, thoughtful, whole, all-around

adverb
all over

verb
circuit, help out
```

**同**

```
preposition
with

pronoun
same

adjective
similar, like, alike

adverb
together

noun
lane
```

**比**

```
noun
ratio

verb
compare, contrast, compete, emulate

particle
particle used for comparison
```

Using the above information, as well as what I would expect to appear on a trend chart, and the assumption that the Chinese sentence is probably a set of nouns, my closest guess is that `周同比` means `Compared to Last Week`. Is that a good translation?

Comment: cf. bkrs: 同比
over the same period
year-on-year; 中国4月物价同比增长2.8%,  "compared to the same period last year", ichacha: 年同比    year-on-year on an annual ba......

Comment: "Compared to Last Week" means 周*环*比. 周同比 means "compare the same week with the last year". Refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite literally it says: 'period same compare', so what will you make of that? You need a context.

过去24周的同比销售额下降了7%
comparing sales volumes over the last 24 weeks （we see） a drop of 7%

Since 周 does not have to mean week, but any cyclic period， 周期, depending on the context, you might write 'cyclic fluctuation' 'periodic swing' 'comparative variation' or things along that line.

Comment: In order to make OP clear on this, 过去24周的同比销售额下降了7%==comparing sales volumes over the last 24 weeks （we see） a drop of 7%. This translation might be wrong. It should be translated as "comparing sales volumes of the last 24 weeks with those from the last year, we see a drop of 7%". My English is not as good as Pedroski, but again the point is to compare data from the same week(s) with last year. In short, weeks data this year VS the same weeks data last year. The rest is how to word it.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, 周同比 means 'to compare with the week of last year'.

Let's say， this is the 25th week of this year, so you want to compare the data (of this week) with the 25th week of last year.